# Is there a standard spreaded way to parse config files

Tags: c, linux, configuration-files

I want to create a configuration file for my program in C.

I know how I can do this and the problem is I have several ideas in my mind.

I was researching but I cannot find any generalized standard way to create and parse config files, so I am afraid that I will just create a file with some kind of structure like this:

```
# Section1
STRING_parameter1          Value1
STRING_parameter2          Value2

# Section2
STRING_other_parameter1    Value3
STRING_other_parameter2    Value4

        ...

        etc
```

And then just parse the file from the different modules, every section in a normal way.

But I am afraid I can come out with some long term problems that only experience can teach and then to have to modify this structure.

That is why I would like to know if there is a better way to do this in order to avoid future issues.

Comment: xml, json, yaml... only half kidding. But don't overthink it, if you think INI-style is sufficient now I wouldn't worry too much about it. You can always wrap something around the parser so if you need to change format you just need to change a self-contained part of your program.

Comment: There's more than one way to do it. Having said that, I've used [libconfig](http://www.hyperrealm.com/oss_libconfig.shtml) successfully in a few projects.

Comment: [The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum)—Andrew S. Tanenbaum, 1988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you may pair the C language with other scripting and parsing languages, like xml, json, yaml, there is a simple standard way that is used by those who want to have C only programming environment. Matter of taste, I guess. You may simply have an ASCII .txt file with predetermined format, read it from C and update it either manually or by some other problem. This is the simplest solution that will be always C compatible.
However, if you want to go json, or yaml, go ahead, by all means. Just keep in mind, that maintenance may be a bit complicated, if your code gets into the hands of someone who does know C, and doesn't know jsom, yaml or xml.
I hope that this answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

From it I can conclude that there are no standard libraries or standard methods and procedures using simply flat C in order to do this.

I will go in the way you say, just having a simple text file with some given format, as the configuration to be read is very basic.

Thanks!